# VS Code: How do I get the individual run or debug button next to each individual test?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, jestjs, tsx

I used to be able to run each test individually by just clicking a run or debug button next to the test itself. But now I don't see that option anymore. Does anyone know how to get that back? I don't want to run the entire suite every time I make a new test.

These are **.test.tsx files**.
My tests

[image]

I want something like this. What settings do I need to change?
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest?